# How do I properly terminate a process with psutil without it becoming a zombie?

Tags: python, linux, psutil

I want to terminate a process gracefully by sending it a SIGTERM signal. Therefore, I tried to find the process and call proc.terminate():

```
[proc] = [proc in psutil.process_iter() if proc.name().lower() == "somename"]
proc.terminate()
```

This works, but leaves a zombie process which `ps aux` shows as `somename <defunct>`. I googled a bit and thought it would maybe help to add `proc.wait(1)` after terminating it, because I need to still listen for the exit status or something, but that didn't help either. I know that the process exits properly because `proc.wait(1)` does not throw a `TimeoutExpired` exception.

How do I terminate a process properly so that it does not become a zombie process using psutil?

Comment: Do you know what a zombie process is, and what makes it a zombie? It's when a child process is killed, but before the parent process reaps it. Since only the actual parent process kan reap its own children, there's really not much more you can do, unless the real parent process is notified of the unexpected child process termination. Also note that while zombie processes can linger, it's not running, it's still terminated.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude but the fact that `proc.wait(1)` succeeded seems to suggest that the python process is indeed the parent process - I did an experiment with trying to reap another process (which was running as the same UID but not a child of the python process), and `proc.wait(1)` raised a `ChildProcessError`. Nonetheless, I think we need a reproducible example.

Comment: I started this process at some other point in my program (which is a web api) via subprocess.run(). How would I reap the process?

Comment: If you yourself created the process, first of all how did you create it? A [mre] would be nice to have. Secondly, once you have created the child process, why do you throw it away instead of keeping the information about it around, for termination and reaping?

Comment: I threw it away because I did not need the info (or thought so) and my API is running multiple worker processes so I would have to save the info to a database or some other persistent storage. Before, I just used `kill` to terminate the process which worked but didn't allow the child processes to clean up after themselves. I will try to create a minimal reproducible example tomorrow. Thanks for your thoughts so far!

Comment: If the parent process continues to run, why not simply keep the child processes in a plain Python list? You might also consider your design, if it's really suitable for the problem you're trying to solve. And don't worry about throwing away a somewhat working program to start fresh after you learned your lessons from the first program. Consider the first program as a way to learn more about the problem at hand, as a kind of throw-away prototype.

Comment: As I said, my program is running with multiple instances because the API needs to be able to answer multiple requests at the same time. Therefore a simple list won't cut it as it can't be shared between API instances. I am running a flask API with multiple gunicorn workers.

Comment: Are the workers supposed to be totally disconnected from their parent processes? Then just create and forget them: Create worker, let worker finish its work, and exit the worker. If the flask handler doesn't exist any more, then the worker processes would be orphaned and the `init` process will take over as their parent and reap them. If you feel the need to force a termination of a worker, then I'd argue that it's a sign of either a bug in the worker process, or a bad design.

Comment: I found the problem: I was running a script that started another process and then exited. The so started process apparently becomes an orphan then, and is handed over to the init process (PID 1) which becomes its new parent. In my case, my application was dockerized and PID 1 was not an init process. I solved it by adding --init to my docker run command